# Stuck while installation/update of Extensions in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, symfony, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the symfony eclipse extensions but failed to do so.

Other components are downloaded successfully, but it tries to download,

org.eclipse.dltk.ui_5.0.0.201310291609.jar and org.eclipse.dltk.core_5.0.0.201310291609.jar from

https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/dltk-nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/org.eclipse.dltk.releng/build/update.site/target/sites/plugins/ which never completes..

Both files are downloaded about 500 - 600 kb and just restarts downloading and just loops..

Its not the internet speed as I have fair speed as I just downloaded the runtime and other components..

This is the same problem while updating the extensions also.
Any one facing the same problem ? Any help here please

Answer (score 2):

You seems trying to install latest development build from composite update site http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/. It has references to other sites (see http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/compositeContent.xml):

```
 1. <child location="http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/dev"/>
 2. <child location="http://download.eclipse.org/tools/pdt/updates/3.2-nightly"/>
 3. <child location="https://hudson.eclipse.org/hudson/job/dltk-nightly/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/org.eclipse.dltk.releng/build/update.site/target/site"/>
```

Instead of using composite update site you can try add first two update site in eclipse install dialog, then download whole 3rd site for dltk from hudson (use 'all files in zip' link) and add it as local update site. Then select symfony update site and install what you need with '[x] Contact all update sites during install to find required software' selected.

Comment: ^^ Thanks for the help :) it worked,, Seems like the hudson link was broken so it caused this problem